# using addin to layout the diagram in EA opens the diagram in the view

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

Using LayoutDiagramEx method to layout the diagram in EA using addin open the diagram in the view.But how to close the diagrams that are opened during the layouting of diagram.Because we want not to open the diagram in view .But it should be autoarranged without opening or how to close the diagram that is opened in the EA using Addin in C#

Comment: I downvoted your question because you are supposed to do your own research before asking a question on SO. Closing a diagram using the API is really obvious and should be clear to anyone who does a basic search in the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you cannot avoid EA to open the diagram when doing the auto-layout.

Closing a diagram is as obvious as `Repository.CloseDiagram(diagramID)`.